# Why am I getting this weird error in iOS simulator?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

What I'm trying to do is place a side bar in my app but [I'm getting this weird error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5jw4.png).

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
>   object with keys (flex, backgroundColor}). If
>   you meant to render a collection of children,
>   use an array instead.
>     in View (at Animatedlmplementation.js:
>   184q)
>     in AnimatedComponent (at SidebarView.js
>   210)
>     in RCTView (at View.js:133)
>     in View (at SidebarView.js:2O3)
>     in SidebarView (at index.ios.js:48)
>     in Bar (at index.ios.js:65)
>     in Provider (at index.ios.js:6q)
>     in DApp (at renderApplication.js:35)
>     in RCTView (at View.js:133)
>     in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
>     in RCTView (at View.js:133)
>     in View (at AppContainer.js:97)

I get that the `react-redux` `<Provider/>` component expects its child prop to be a single ReactElement hence why I wrapped everything in a single component called `<Bar/>`.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text} from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Application from './pages/Application';
import store from './redux';
import api from './utilities/api';
import SideBar from 'react-native-sidebar';

export default class DApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            isLoading: true
        }
        console.log("something");
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        api.getData().then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                data: res.data
            })
        });
    }

    renderLeftSideBar() {
        return(
            <Text>Something here for left side bar!</Text>
        );
    }

    renderRightSideBar() {
        return(
            <Text>Something here for right side bar!</Text>
        );
    }

    renderContent() {
        return(
            <Text>The content!</Text>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const Bar = () => {
            return(
                <SideBar>
                    leftSideBar = {this.renderLeftSideBar()}
                    rightSideBar = {this.renderRightSideBar()}
                    style = {{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>{this.renderContent()}
                    <Application/>
                </SideBar>
            );
        }

        if(this.state.isLoading) {
            console.log("The data is: " + this.state.data);
        } else {
            console.log("Else got executed");
        }

        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Bar/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('DApp', () => DApp);
```

Comment: <SideBar>
                    leftSideBar = {this.renderLeftSideBar()}
                    rightSideBar = {this.renderRightSideBar()}
                    style = {{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>{this.renderContent()}
                    <Application/>
                </SideBar>
looks like this properties should have been fed into Sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like there's a typo in your code - `leftSideBar`, `rightSideBar`, and `style` attributes are not associated with `<SideBar>`, because you have an extra `>` - I think that if you just used

```
        return(
            <SideBar
                leftSideBar = {this.renderLeftSideBar()}
                rightSideBar = {this.renderRightSideBar()}
                style = {{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>{this.renderContent()}
                <Application/>
            </SideBar>
        );
```

you'd probably be good

Comment: Great, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

leftSideBar, rightSideBar and style should be props of the SideBar component, like this:

```
<SideBar leftSideBar = {this.renderLeftSideBar()} rightSideBar = {this.renderRightSideBar()} style = {{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>{this.renderContent()}
                <Application/>
            </SideBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the Bar component does not return valid JSX. Try something like:

```
import { your other components ..., View } from 'react-native';

<SideBar>
  {this.renderLeftSideBar()}
  {this.renderRightSideBar()}
  <View style = {{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
    {this.renderContent()}
  </View>
  <Application/>
</SideBar>
```